# MySQL + VB.NET - TabControl and multiple DataGridviews

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a problem with my DataGridViews, actually i have a form with a TabControl with 8 tabs, each tab have a DataGridView control. I'm populating them when the form load, the problem is that i got kind of a limit here, only 3 DataGridViews are getting populated, not 3 specific ones but any 3 i put first on my code. I'm populating them manually, doing a mysql query, filling a DataTable and then making the data source equal to the DataTable.

Any ideas?

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Data

Public Class frmMantenimiento
    Dim conn As MySqlConnection
    Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand
    Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim dataEmp As New DataTable
    Dim dataNomi As New DataTable
    Dim dataPres As New DataTable
    Dim dataGast As New DataTable
    Dim dataAmon As New DataTable
    Dim dataHora As New DataTable
    Dim SQL As String

    Public Sub FillEmps()
        conn = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; user id=root; password=; database=arj;")

        myCommand.Connection = conn
        SQL = "SELECT IDEmpleado as ID, Nombre, Cargo FROM Empleados"

        Try
            conn.Open()

            Try
                myCommand.Connection = conn
                myCommand.CommandText = SQL

                myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
                myAdapter.Fill(dataEmp)

                dgvConsEmp.DataSource = dataEmp

                dgvConsEmp.Columns(0).Width = 30
                dgvConsEmp.Columns(1).Width = 200
                dgvConsEmp.Columns(2).Width = 200

            Catch myerror As MySqlException
                MsgBox("Ocurrió un error leyendo la base de datos: " & myerror.Message)
            End Try
        Catch myerror As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show("Ocurrió un error conectando a la base de datos: " & myerror.Message)
        Finally
            If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then conn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub FillNom()
        conn = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; user id=root; password=; database=arj;")

        myCommand.Connection = conn
        SQL = String.Empty
        SQL = "SELECT IDNomina as ID, Fecha, MontoBruto as 'Monto Bruto', MontoNeto as 'Monto Neto', CantidadEmpleados as Empleados FROM Nomina"

        Try
            conn.Open()

            Try
                myCommand.Connection = conn
                myCommand.CommandText = SQL

                myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
                myAdapter.Fill(dataNomi)

                dgvConsNomi.DataSource = dataNomi

                dgvConsNomi.Columns(0).Width = 30

            Catch myerror As MySqlException
                MsgBox("Ocurrió un error leyendo la base de datos: " & myerror.Message)
            End Try
        Catch myerror As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show("Ocurrió un error conectando a la base de datos: " & myerror.Message)
        Finally
            If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then conn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub FillPres()
        conn = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; user id=root; password=; database=arj;")

        myCommand.Connection = conn
        SQL = String.Empty
        SQL = "SELECT IDPrestamo as ID, IDEmpleado as 'ID Empleado', MontoInicial as Monto, Fecha, MontoDescuento as Descuento, FormaDescuento as Recurrencia, Status FROM Prestamos"

        Try
            conn.Open()

            Try
                myCommand.Connection = conn
                myCommand.CommandText = SQL

                myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
                myAdapter.Fill(dataPres)

                dgvConsPres.DataSource = dataPres

                dgvConsPres.Columns(0).Width = 30

            Catch myerror As MySqlException
                MsgBox("Ocurrió un error leyendo la base de datos: " & myerror.Message)
            End Try
        Catch myerror As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show("Ocurrió un error conectando a la base de datos: " & myerror.Message)
        Finally
            If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then conn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub FillGast()
        conn = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; user id=root; password=; database=arj;")

        myCommand.Connection = conn
        SQL = String.Empty
        SQL = "SELECT IDGasto as ID, IDEmpleado as 'ID Empleado', Monto, Fecha, Concepto, IDUsuario as Creador FROM GastosEmpleados"

        Try
            conn.Open()

            Try
                myCommand.Connection = conn
                myCommand.CommandText = SQL

                myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
                myAdapter.Fill(dataGast)

                Me.dgvConsGast.DataSource = dataGast

                Me.dgvConsGast.Columns(0).Width = 30

            Catch myerror As MySqlException
                MsgBox("Ocurrió un error leyendo la base de datos: " & myerror.Message)
            End Try
        Catch myerror As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show("Ocurrió un error conectando a la base de datos: " & myerror.Message)
        Finally
            If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then conn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub FillAmon()
        conn = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; user id=root; password=; database=arj;")

        myCommand.Connection = conn
        SQL = "SELECT IDAmonestacion as ID, TipoAmonestacion as Tipo, Descripcion, IDUsuario as Creador FROM Amonestaciones"

        Try
            conn.Open()

            Try
                myCommand.Connection = conn
                myCommand.CommandText = SQL

                myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
                myAdapter.Fill(dataAmon)

                dgvConsAmon.DataSource = dataAmon

                dgvConsAmon.Columns(0).Width = 30

            Catch myerror As MySqlException
                MsgBox("Ocurrió un error leyendo la base de datos: " & myerror.Message)
            End Try
        Catch myerror As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show("Ocurrió un error conectando a la base de datos: " & myerror.Message)
        Finally
            If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then conn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub FillHora()
        conn = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; user id=root; password=; database=arj;")

        myCommand.Connection = conn
        SQL = "SELECT IDControlHorario as ID, IDEmpleado as 'ID Empleado', Fecha, Hora FROM ControlHorario"

        Try
            conn.Open()

            Try
                myCommand.Connection = conn
                myCommand.CommandText = SQL

                myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
                myAdapter.Fill(dataHora)

                dgvConsHora.DataSource = dataHora

                dgvConsHora.Columns(0).Width = 30

            Catch myerror As MySqlException
                MsgBox("Ocurrió un error leyendo la base de datos: " & myerror.Message)
            End Try
        Catch myerror As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show("Ocurrió un error conectando a la base de datos: " & myerror.Message)
        Finally
            If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then conn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub


    Private Sub frmMantenimiento_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        FillEmps()
        FillNom()
        FillPres()
        FillGast()
        FillAmon()
        FillHora()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of code duplication that you can refactor.  But, I think the root cause is that you are not reinitializing `myCommand` and `myAdapter` variables in each `FillX()` method.  So, I would start by making the `conn`, `myCommand`, `myAdapter`, and `SQL` variables local to each `FillX()` method.

Then I would refactor the code to apply the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle and eliminate duplicate code.

Comment: Not working even declaring new variables for each FillX(), maybe a connection problem, too many queries at the same time or something?